# Getting correct ID without sharing URL

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

I have an Angular 4 application where I am trying to fetch a single row (using ID) from a MySQL database. I am using NodeJS with ExpressJS. However, I am struggling finding a way to get the ID from the URL without sharing the exact URL-path, as that would lead to the website only rendering the JSON-object, and not the components.

*server.js*

`app.get('api/books/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});`

If the URL is `localhost:3000/books/3`, the console will log `:id`.
 `localhost:3000/api/books/3` will however log the correct ID to the console. The issue is that using the latter as my URL in my Angular routing will result in a shared path, which will not work.

Here's an example of how I use Angular's HttpModule to send a GET-request to the server:

```
this.http.get('api/books/:id')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.bookDetail = data;
});
```

Here is my path from the routing using Angular's RouterModule:

```
{ path: 'books/:id', component: BookDetailComponent }
```

How would I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function that on the init of that component, the angular app triggers the HTTP request to the server. for example, I have a blog application.

```
  { path: 'blogs/:id', component: BlogComponent },

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.blog = params.id);
    this.getBlog(this.blog);}

  getBlog(blog) {
    this.blogService.getBlog(blog).subscribe(
      data => { this.foundBlog = data;
        if (data.comments) {
          this.comments = data.comments;
        }

  getBlog(blog): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/blogs/${blog}`).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

the first is my route, the second is the init function on my blog component

the third is the get blog function on the blog component

the last is the get blog function on my blogservice, that send the HTTP request

hopefully that helps.

Comment: That worked like a charm! However, I needed to change `'http://localhost:3000/api/books/${id}'` to `'http://localhost:3000/api/books/' + id`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!